# How to get the current build's node name in jenkins using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job running in Jenkins and I want to know the name of the node it's running on. Is there a way to get the node name from within the job's Groovy script?

I have tried the below code:

```
print currentBuild.getBuiltOn().getNodeName()
```

the error is:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun getBuiltOn
```

I also tried this:

```
def build = currentBuild.build()
print build.getExecutor().getOwner().getNode().getNodeName()
```

but the result is ''.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is an environment variable 'NODE_NAME' which has this.

You can access it like this:

```
echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"
```

When you are editing a pipeline job, you can find all the available environment variables by going to the "pipeline syntax" help link (left of page) then look for the "Global Variables" section and click through to the "Global Variables Reference". There is a section "env" that lists the environment variables available.

Comment: For me this prints `NODE_NAME = null`. Is this a bug in pipeline?

Comment: You get null if the pipeline does not allocate a node - say if you have "agent none" in a declarative pipeline. This is using a "flyweight executor" on Jenkins which does not declare a node or take an executor - it is mentioned on here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

Comment: It might also be because you are putting that command inside the `script` block in declarative pipeline. If you wish to use it inside the `script` block then simply `${NODE_NAME}`

Comment: What if you switch nodes in a stage? the `env.NODE_NAME` doesn't change and stays what the original is. How do you get the nested node name?

Comment: It's null when used in "options" immediately under "stage", even if NODE_NAME is visible in the "sh" blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not documented, but indeed Node and Executor objects can be obtained from CpsThread class of the pipeline. Of course, they are defined only inside node { } block:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread;

@NonCPS
obtainContextVariables() {
    return CpsThread.current().getContextVariables().values;
}

node('myNode') {
    print('Node: ' + obtainContextVariables().findAll(){ x -> x instanceof Computer }[0].getNode())
    print('Executor: ' + obtainContextVariables().findAll(){ x -> x instanceof Executor }[0])
}
```

Comment: Explanation for my answer. It can be useful for the case if somebody needs not just a node name as a String, but the Node object for accessing of further stuff like Channel, build log file etc. for further intervention into internals of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the node name this way:

`build.getExecutor().getOwner().getDisplayName()`