# How to get slave name on which jenkins pipeline job is executed via API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to get slave name on which jenkins pipeline job is executed via API.
For free style jobs I am able to get using:

```
JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER/api/json?tree=builtOn
```

But for pipeline job, this info is not present in JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you need to use the API instead of accessing the build environment variables (as answered here: [How to get the current build's node name in jenkins using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757172/how-to-get-the-current-builds-node-name-in-jenkins-using-groovy)) e.g.
String runningOn = env.NODE_NAME;
?

Comment: Aaah.. you need to do this remotely, having only the "job name"... ignore my answer :(