# Dynamic parameter value depending on Jenkins agent label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I got choice parameter defined in pipeline consisting of couple of items. I got 2 types of jenkins agents, each of the with custom label set on. Is it possible to set ordering of choice items depending on which agent is running pipeline. I'm thinking of sth like this:

```
def VALUES

pipeline {
   agent {
      label 'agentone || agenttwo'}
   }

   //not an actual code
   if agent_name == agentone
     VALUES=['item1', 'item2']
   if agent_name == agentwo
     VALUES=['item2', 'item1']
   ////////
.....   

     parameters {
        choice(name: 'ITEMS', choices: "${VALUES}.join('\n')")
     }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use the enviroment variable called NODE_NAME
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758361/12451425

Comment: For Jenkins to present you your "Build with Parameters" page, it has to finish evaluating the `parameters` clause. At this stage, Jenkins has no idea what agent will run your stage, for it to actually select an agent it needs to get past the "Build with Parameters" page.

Comment: You could use `NODE_NAME` variable in an `input` step.